# JFace data binding occurs after other events

Tags: java, data-binding, model, listener, jface

I want to do something based on the model change, e.g. if user enters text in the Text SWT widget, I would like to do something based on that. But the problem is, if I use e.g. key listener on the widget, it will get called before the data binding process occurs and therefore the behaviour would'nt be consistent. One way around this is to do the logic inside the binding process, but this is not really a convinient way of handling this problem. Suggestions?

So basically, what I need is an event listener, which is triggered after the data binding occures (on some specified widget of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IChangeListener` to listen for changes on the model observable value. This will be called after the model has been updated from the target.

Something like:

```
IObservableValue targetOV = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(text control);

IObservableValue modelOV = PojoProperties.value("your field").observe(object); 

bindContext.bindValue(targetOV, modelOV);

modelOV.addChangeListener(change listener);
```

Comment: How can I bind it with the specified widget?

Comment: The last line was what I needed. Ty.

Comment: One more problem though: if the validation status returned is equal to ValidationStatus.error, the model doesn't get updated. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I don't see anything useful in the binding code for that case.